# Roma 2018 - Alfonso Cuaron - beach wedding song

Tags: folk

I'm trying to identify the title of the [simple beach wedding music](http://youtube.com/watch?v=MFGvzFPx-i0&feature=youtu.be), performed by a local Mexican orchestra in *Roma* (the great movie on Netflix, Venice festival winner, from Alfonso Cuaron)

It is not on the soundtrack list of the movie, nor in the separate movie soundtrack record/spotify.

It's 1 hour 57 minutes into the movie (link above).

I imagine anyone from Mexico could know it,